# Check if a timestamp string is within a time range

Tags: python

I need check if a timestamp string is into a time range:

```
tt = '26-12-2012 18:32:51'
t1 = datetime.timedelta(0, 28800) #08:00 hrs
t2 = datetime.timedelta(0, 68400) #19:00 hrs
```

To compare do I need convert the timestamp into a timedelta?, how can I do that, to compare like:

```
if tt >= t1 and tt <= t2:
```

Thanks..

Comment: Comparing a datetime to a timedelta? What exactly does it mean?

Comment: To do this you have to know when the timedelta was created. A timedelta only deals with the difference between two times, so if you only have one absolute time I don't know what you hope to do with it... Do you want to see how much time has passed since tt?

Comment: what time range are you trying to search for?

Comment: I'm trying to check if the timestamp are into the time range 08:00 - 19:00

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, construct a datetime object with `datetime.strptime`:

```
>>> t = datetime.datetime.strptime('26-12-2012 18:32:51', '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
>>> t
datetime.datetime(2012, 12, 26, 18, 32, 51)
```

Now, construct a second datetime object which only represents the date portion:

```
>>> t2 = t.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0)
```

From that you can get a `datetime.timedelta` suitable for comparing with your other `timedelta`s:

```
>>> t - t2
datetime.timedelta(0, 66771)
>>> dt = t - t2
>>> dt1 = datetime.timedelta(0, 28800) #08:00 hrs
>>> dt2 = datetime.timedelta(0, 68400) #08:00 hrs
>>> dt > dt1
True
>>> dt2 > dt > dt1
True
```

Comment: That is a great answer! Worked great!